# Unable to install node-sass in my project

Tags: node.js, node-sass

I am doing wes-bos Learn Node course. When I run npm start it shows - cannot find module node-sass. And when I try to run `npm install node-sass --save`, it gives me the following errors.

[image: Errors]

[image: Errors]

Comment: Just a tip I was getting the same error message about not being able to access the url to install node sass, but I ran the command `node_modules/.bin/node-sass -v` and found that sass was in fact installed.

Comment: node-sass should download prebuilt binaries . Since I am in a corporate network that is causing isuse

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Uninstall node-sass: `npm uninstall node-sass`
Delete `package-lock.json`, and clean the cache: `npm cache clean --force`, then do `npm update`, `npm install`, `npm update`. then again try to install node sass: `npm install node-sass`.

If this doesn't work, Try to rebuild node-sass:

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

If that too doesn't work then i suggest to delete `package-lock.json`, `node-modules` and `npm cache` folder and do `npm install` , to install all your dependencies again. make sure you have a package.json file with all your dependencies listed.

The package-lock.json file has some issues(it doesn't update when package.json changes) as mentioned here:https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16866
"Touching package.json by hand may make your package.json to be incompatible with package-lock.json". do `npm update` to update the `package-lock.json` file.
to completely disable package-lock creation:
`npm config set package-lock false`

**Update (16 july 2022):**
As node-sass is depricated(https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass), it is recommended to use dart-sass instead and upgrade the node version to v16 at least.

Comment: When I do npm install after deleting the node_modules, it still gives me that python error. And npm rebuild node-sass doesn't work.

Comment: did you delete the npm cache folder also , on windows, i had to delete my node modules, npm cache, npm folder(in c:/user/username/appdata/roaming ), and also i did a reinstall of node js because some of the modules got corrupted. so download the executable file of node js ,don't use the zip file

Comment: This helped me a lot - thanks. As an FYI to others, I did not run the suggested "npm update" as this would have tried to update all of my packages and would have been risky in my project (lot of dependencies). Still, the first 3 steps worked without the need to run that command.

Comment: I tried the same process with Yarn and it worked fine. Thank you

Comment: I tried this but not worked, then I downgrade the node version using NVM to v16 and it works.

Answer (score 33):

Try this

```
sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-sass --save
```