# error 404 installing node-sass --save-dev

Tags: node.js, saas

im a new beginner in html/css development with windows 10. I'm trying to use Saas for my website project but when I am trying to install node-sass, I get the following errors:

```
PS C:\wamp64\www\flexbox> npm install node-saas --save-dev
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: node-saas@latest
```

npm version is : 6.3.0
node version is : 8.11.3
I've already try this: [Unable to install node-sass in my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515077/unable-to-install-node-sass-in-my-project) but it doesn't work. 
I'v try to open cmd as administrator, and try executing the same commands. Same problem again...

Can you please help me to find a solution ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You're installing `node-saas`. You meant to install `node-sass`, double `s` and a single `a`.